# Using Oracle ON COMMIT option on materialized over database link

Tags: plsql, database-trigger, materialized-views, database-link

I have a question.

I have a table on **database 1** called **Distribution_id** which will hold no more than 2000 records at a time, I have a materialized view called **Mv_Distribution_id** which is a copy **Distribution_id** table on **database 2**.

I want to do a quick refresh of the materialized view **Mv_Distribution_id** on **database 2** when ever there is a change to the data in the database table **Distribution_id** on **database 1**.

If the materialized view **Mv_Distribution_id** on **database 2** has been created with the "**ON COMMIT**" option will it see that the database table on **database 1** as been changed and automatically fast refreshed the materialized view, or doesn't the "**ON COMMIT**" option work over a database link and i'd need to refresh it using a packaged procedure or database table trigger on Distribution_id table.

The reason I've created a materialized view is sometimes database 1 is not available to database 2 therefore creating a copy is a quick solution.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Oracle 11g Replication - Using refresh on commit with remote database (database links)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12248186/oracle-11g-replication-using-refresh-on-commit-with-remote-database-database)

Answer (score 0):

As [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/DWHSG/refresh.htm#DWHSG8364) says:

> A materialized view can be refreshed automatically using the ON COMMIT method. Therefore, whenever a transaction commits which has updated the tables on which a materialized view is defined, those changes are automatically reflected in the materialized view. The advantage of using this approach is you never have to remember to refresh the materialized view.

Materialized views (especially) make sense over database links because operations over the link can be slow, so it is handy to have data *here*. So ... no problem with it, I'd say.

Comment: I've been looking all over the internet and I'm not sure if "ON COMMIT" method can be done if the base table of a materialized view is on another database, I don't see any examples of this.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12248186/oracle-11g-replication-using-refresh-on-commit-with-remote-database-database